# Why append elements not a draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I make all elements with an "image" class draggable.
Then I append more "image" elements to the page.
Why aren't the appended elements draggable?

```js
$(function() {

  $('.image').draggable(); //Draggable image (Jquery UI)

  $('.button').click(function() { //append more image
    $('body').append('<img class="image" src="http://nuclearpixel.com/content/icons/2010-02-09_stellar_icons_from_space_from_2005/earth_128.png">')
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-beta.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<img class="image" src="http://nuclearpixel.com/content/icons/2010-02-09_stellar_icons_from_space_from_2005/earth_128.png">
<button class="button">Append image</button>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/coolerprinter/0jxghvaa/1/)

Comment: because it does not magically bind to the new elements. You need to run that code again.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `.draggable();` on the newly created image on every button click.

```
$(function(){

  $('.image').draggable(); //Draggable image (Jquery UI)

  $('.button').click(function(){     //append more image
    var img = $('<img class="image" src="http://nuclearpixel.com/content/icons/2010-02-09_stellar_icons_from_space_from_2005/earth_128.png">');
    img.draggable();
    $('body').append(img);
  });

}) //End of script
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0jxghvaa/2/

Answer (score 1):

You're instantiating the `draggable()` plugin on the `.image` elements at load. Any elements added to the DOM after that will need the plugin instantiating on them once they are created. Try this:

```
$('.image').draggable();

$('.button').click(function() {
    var $img = $('<img class="image" src="http://nuclearpixel.com/content/icons/2010-02-09_stellar_icons_from_space_from_2005/earth_128.png">').appendTo('body');
    $img.draggable();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Newly added elements will not be automatically drag-able (only those elements existing initially).

Inside your function, try re-declaring that the element will be drag-able, AFTER it is created:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('body').append('<img class="image" src="http://nuclearpixel.com/content/icons/2010-02-09_stellar_icons_from_space_from_2005/earth_128.png">');
    $('.image').draggable();
});
```

Comment: this is bad practice as you'll be reassigning the event to every previously created img with that class. just fyi

Comment: Indeed - although he hasn't stated that there will be more than one .image element, but I suppose I should assume there will be!

Would instead be better to just target the specific HTML just appended (possibly by adding a unique ID and selecting by ID to add the draggable() function).